# The minimum possible dimension of node embedding for network homophily

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, graph-theory, network

**Background:** Network homophily refers to the theory in network science which states that, based on node attributes, similar nodes may be more likely to attach to each other than dissimilar ones.
(Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_homophily)

Here, we want to study homophily merely from the perspective of node embedding.

---

Given a simple graph (network) $G = (V,E)$, we find node embedding $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{|V| \times d}$ of the nodes in $V$, where $d$ is the dimension of node embedding.
For each $v \in V$, we let
$N_v \subseteq V$ denote the set of neighbors of $v$,
and let $Z_v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ denote the embedding of $v$.
We formally define network homophily.

**Defenition:** Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and node embedding $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{|V| \times d}$, we say $G$ has

- *local homophily* (w.r.t $Z$) if for each $v \in V$, $\min_{u \in N_v} Z_u \cdot Z_v \geq \max_{w \notin N_v} Z_w \cdot Z_v$
- *global homophily* (w.r.t $Z$) if $\min_{(u, v) \in E} Z_u \cdot Z_v \geq \max_{(w, x) \notin E} Z_w \cdot Z_x$

**Note:** Clearly, if $d$ is large enough (e.g., $d \geq |E|$), we can easily find such node embedding.

**Question 1:** Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, what is the minimum dimension $d$ such that there exists  node embedding $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{|V| \times d}$ such that $G$ has local/global homophily?

**Question 2:** What properties can make such a minimum $d$ smaller/larger?

Comment: So I've tried this problem a couple times now, and I always run into what does it mean in this context for the dot product to be zero? What defines membership in $N_v$? Is there anything dually implied by existence of an edge between nodes?

Comment: Expanding the dot product puts the dimension, $d$, in the upper limit of the sum: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^d (Z_a^i\cdot Z_b^i)$. Further assuming the embedding to be an injective map seems to yield preservation of simplicity in the image graph. Other than that, I think we need more info.